# OpenLayers caching quota

Tags: javascript, local-storage, openlayers, quota

I'm using OpenLayers to cache map tiles. It uses LocalStorage as storage mechanism for the cached tiles. There is an event that fires when I run out of space (i.e. at 5MB), and I have the option of completely clearing or iterating the cache.

I am using LocalStorage to store other objects also, such as settings, so its not good if I run out of space.

How can I set a max limit for tiles cached by OpenLayers? Preferably as a size limitation (not number of items).

Answer (score 1):

Good question. By reading the [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Control/CacheWrite.js) of the control this is not possible. You would have to modify the CacheWrite class to add a `maxLimit` property or something like that. Another solution would be to override the whole control and use HTML5 File API.

Answer (score 0):

Use pouch db to store tiles. It will remove the 5mb limit.